# Image encryption throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, image, encryption, base64, aes

I am creating a program that encrypts data. De and encryption works perfectly fine. But when decrypting an image I get an error. I am very greatful for any help!

When trying to decrypt my image using the cat_encrypt method like this:

```java
 String encrypted = encrypt.cat_encrypt(getFileContent(jf.getSelectedFile()), pass);
 Files.writeString(Path.of(jf.getSelectedFile().getPath()), encrypted);
```

I get the following error:

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input byte array has incorrect ending byte at 54808
```

Here is my encryption method:

```java
public static String cat_encrypt(String text, String pass) {
        try {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            Key key = new SecretKeySpec(messageDigest.digest(pass.getBytes(UTF_8)), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes(UTF_8));
            byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(encrypted);
            return new String(encoded, UTF_8);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException |
                 BadPaddingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot encrypt", e);
        }
    }
```

And this is my decryption method:

```java
public static String cat_decrypt(String text, String pass)  {
        try {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            Key key = new SecretKeySpec(messageDigest.digest(pass.getBytes(UTF_8)), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(DECRYPT_MODE, key);

            byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(text.getBytes(UTF_8));
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(decoded);
            return new String(decrypted, UTF_8);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException |
                 BadPaddingException e) {

            try {
                sendError((e.getClass().getSimpleName()));
            }catch (Exception sE){e.printStackTrace();}

            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot decrypt", e);
        }
    }
```

I call the decrypt method like this:

```
String decrypted = encrypt.cat_decrypt(getFileContent(jf.getSelectedFile()), pass);
```

The full error code:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input byte array has incorrect ending byte at 54808
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:876)
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:566)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead [edit] your question to contain the error message/stack trace as formatted text.

Comment: If you are handling images as `String` then you almost certainly already did something wrong (unless you always handle a Base64 encoded version, which I suspect you don't). So the place where you convert your image to `String` is where it gets broken, way before you call your encryption/decryption methods.

Comment: @JoachimSauer thank's for the reply! Could you help me when I attach the image to string method? What method would you recommend for me to encrypt images securely?

Comment: When handling image data you should take care to always keep it in `byte[]` or related types (such as `ByteBuffer` and handle with `InputStream`/`OutputStream` instead of `Writer`/`Reader`). That's the primary thing you need to fix: change your methods (or add new ones) to accept the data as `byte[]` directly and return that again.

Comment: **Security warning**: for everyone else - do not use the encryption scheme in the post as it uses an **UNSECURE** AES mode ("AES" = "AES/ECB") and as "key derivation" the already **broken** hash algorithm "MD5" is used. Better use modes like "AES/CBC" or "AES/GCM" and a key derivation like "Argon2" or "PBKDF2", thanks.

Comment: @MichaelFehr could you suggest any "simple to code" library to encrypt images without much to do? The image encryption is a really small part of my project, but still, it should securely store images.